# Holomorphic Foliations of 3-manifolds with boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, foliations

Let $M$ be a 3-manifold $M$ with boundary $\partial M$, and endow $\partial M$ with the structure of a Riemann surface. Does there exist a foliation of $M$ by Riemann surfaces such that $\partial M$ is a leaf of the foliation? If not, are there sufficiency criteria for the existence of such a foliation?

Comment: Do you allow singular leaves? The closed 3-ball seems the obvious counterexample.

Comment: @BenMcKay, I don't want to allow singular leaves. The closed 3-ball does seem to provide a counter-example. I'd still be interested to know whether there are already-studied sufficiency criteria for such a foliation.